# What is difference between query syntax in sql

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I am wondering about performance of different query syntax in SQL.

I can execute query like :

**1 - Using EXEC**

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = ' SELECT * from tableName'
EXEC (@sql)
```

**2 - Simple statement**

```
SELECT * from tableName
```

From above 2 option, Which would be the better one in terms of performance OR in other aspect !?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I downvoted because: First you should be able to test performance impacts yourself. (I would guess there is no performance difference.) Second your "other aspects" - what do you mean? Should I talk about one line vs. three? Or how you should label variables? Or if "select *" is good practice? This is in my opinion not a useful question.

Comment: Here, I use simple query for simplicity. In actual, there are joins of multiple tables and specific columns which need to expose.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the syntax used. If you are using something different, then please add the correct tag for your DBMS.

Comment: @Naresh  Even with more complex queries I guess (without any testing) that there is no performance impacts between these two variants. But why do you not test it yourself?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : Thanks. I am using Sql Server.

Comment: @Seb: In my case, option 1 is taking less time compare to 2. And I was trying to know, the general difference provided by SQL as per their syntax, by this question.

Comment: I highly doubt that the dynamic sql took less time... They should take the same time OR the non-dynamic one will be marginally tiny bit faster as it has less parsing to do...

Comment: Yes Milney. I read it from MSDN link, answered by destination-data. But, as I commented above, I my case, the dynamic sql taking less time.

Comment: This question was flagged as primarily opinion based, and it indeed does appear to be soliciting an opinion at first glance. However, I'm going to leave this open because it is asking about the *performance* of 2 different methods, which can be evaluated objectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  The second is static.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Although static SQL works well in many situations, there is a class of applications in which the data access cannot be determined in advance.

Static requires less typing.  For that reason allow I would recommend you use it where possible.

Answer (score 1):

"*Which would be the better one in terms of performance*"
The short answer is, it *depends*.

In the example you posted there will be no difference because both queries are very simple and will produce the same execution plan when executed. There are cases where dynamic SQL can help performance though. Using this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE ##test (id int identity PRIMARY KEY, someCol int NOT NULL)
INSERT ##test (someCol)
SELECT TOP(10000) abs(checksum(newid())%1000000) FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;
```

Let's say we had a requirement to develop a query that returns the TOP 100 records from ##test where someCol <= 100000. There is also a requirement to accept a parameter called @sortBySomeCol; if it's 1 then the query should return the *lowest* 100 records (sorted by SomeCol) otherwise *any* records where someCol is less than/equal to 100000 will do.

Here's what a solution might look like with and without dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sortBySomeCol bit = 1;

-- Dynamic SQL version
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 
'SELECT TOP (100) * 
 FROM ##test 
 WHERE someCol <= 100000
 '+CASE @sortBySomeCol WHEN 1 THEN 'ORDER BY someCol;' ELSE ';' END;

EXEC (@sql);

-- Alternative method
SELECT TOP (100) *
FROM ##test 
WHERE someCol <= 100000
ORDER BY CASE @sortBySomeCol WHEN 1 THEN someCol END;
```

Notice that the execution plans are almost identical (that scalar operator is insignificant) :

[image: execution plans]

The most costly part of the plan is that TOP N sort. It is required, however, because there is no index available to handle the sort. Now let's change @sortBySomeCol to 0 and run the query again. Here's the new plan:

[image]

The Dynamic SQL soluion does not include the TOP N Sort but the second solution does even though the sort is not required.

It's worth noting that you can improve the second query by including OPTION (RECOMPILE) or doing something like this:

```
IF @sortBySomeCol = 1
  SELECT TOP (100) *
  FROM ##test 
  WHERE someCol <= 100000
  ORDER BY CASE @sortBySomeCol WHEN 1 THEN someCol END
ELSE
  SELECT TOP (100) *
  FROM ##test 
  WHERE someCol <= 100000;
```

Again, it depends on what you are doing.